# Log4net Logging at two different file in the same application

Tags: logging, log4net, quartz.net, log4net-configuration

I am using log4net for logging. And my application also using quartz.net for job scheduling. The problem is that both quartz.net logs and my custom logs are printing in the same log file. I am searching out methods for logging on two different files but found no solution. Can anyone guide me how to configure logger to log on different files, one file for quartz.net logs and other file for my application's custom logs.

Answer (score 2):

If you have common root namespace for you application something like this might work:

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="QuartzFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="quartznet.log" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="AppFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="app.log" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="Quartz">
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="QuartzFileAppender" />
    </root> 
    <logger name="YourAppRootNameSpace">
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="AppFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```